# Writing Files using Executor in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, fork-join, threadpoolexecutor

I have a `List<Map<String,String>>` ie; List of Maps. Each Map has `File Name` as `Key` and `File Content` as `Value`.

I have more than 25 Lakh Maps in above List. My requirement is to iterate through this List and create Files in to an output folder reading each Map key and Value. So at the end I will have 25 lakh Files. It takes more than 4hrs. Then I stop the program. I dont know the exact time that would take if I run the program for whole 25lakh records.

I need to optimize this using Multithreading.

How do I optimize this using Java `Executors/ Fork/ Join` (I have `Java 7`)

Answer (score 4):

If you're writing your files on a single disk I don't think adding more threads will really help. Your program is IO-bound, not CPU-intensive.

Comment: This is possible, but if it's taking 4 hours to process 25 files then either there's a lot of pre-processing going on (that could benefit from multi-threading) or else these are humongous files.

Comment: Possible yes. But the description of the problem does not state anything like that. Based on what he describes his app is just iterating through the list, creating a file with the key and outputing the value as file content.

Comment: It is 25 lakh (2.5 million) files not 25

Comment: Yes. There is some pre processing time involved in preparing that List. It fetches records from DB and converts those to List of Maps. For fetching records I use Spring Batch.

Comment: OK. But do you do anything with your list of maps before writing all the files on disk ? And what takes "4 hours" exactly ? Retrieving from the DB + writing the files or just writing the files ? Again : if it takes 4 hours to iterate through your list and creating the files, adding more threads will not help.

Comment: To get the exact problem I tried for 2 lakh records only. Retrieving records from DB + Writing files takes arround 3hrs. But my program should run for min 10lakh records in min to min time period. Cant keep CPU busy for more than 5hrs in creating files.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and a class that implements [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html).

```
public class Processor implements Runnable {
    private final Map<String, String> map;

    public Processor(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Do work here
    }
}

ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor();
for(Map<String, String> map : list) {
    executor.execute(new Processor(map));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parallelization may be achieved by splitting problem in as many sub-problem as processor available. For a list iterator, you may iterate sub-lists:

```
int nThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1;
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( nThreads );
int interval = list.size()/parallel.nThreads;
int from     = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < nThreads; ++i ) {
   int to = ( i == nThreads - 1 ) ? 1000 : from + interval;
   exec.submit( new Search( from, to, list ));
   from = to;
}
exec.shutdown();
exec.awaitTermination( 1, TimeUnit.DAYS );
```

The class `Search` is used to do the job (creating files).

Example of `Search` class:

```
class Search implements Runnable {

  final int from;
  final int to;
  final List< Map< String, String >> list;

  Search( int from, int to, List< Map< String, String >> list ) {
     this.from = from;
     this.to   = to;
     this.list = list;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(){
     for( int b = from; b < to; ++b ) {
        Map< String, String > map = list.get(b);
        ...
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note:

As @vtheron said, "the program is more of IO bound rather than CPU bound", so adding more of threads, you will be wasting more CPU cycles in context switches which is not at all required here.

I guess your current benchmark is 2.5 million in 4 hours, So What is the current implementation?

Hardware configuration will also play a vital role in performance improvement, consider looking at this.